# Ubuntu 20.04 simply stopped recognizing my Bluetooth adapter

Tags: bluetooth

I've been running Ubuntu 20.04 for a long time but recently bluetooth has been getting squirrely. I installed blueman and then it worked fine again. Today I rebooted and now it doesn't appear to recognize I have a bluetooth adapter at all. It is an Inspiron 15 3000 with a built in bluetooth adapter. When I run rfkill all I get is:

```
rfkill list

0: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

No bluetooth.

When I run `bluetoothctl`

```
Waiting to connect to bluetoothd...
```

And then it just sits there.

When I run    `sudo lshw -c network`

```
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: enp1s0
       version: 07
       serial: c0:3e:ba:0f:03:77
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.11.0-27-generic duplex=full firmware=rtl8106e-1_0.0.1 06/29/12 ip=192.168.11.139 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:16 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:c1404000-c1404fff memory:c1400000-c1403fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 31
       serial: 8c:c8:4b:cd:ef:b5
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=5.11.0-27-generic firmware=WLAN.TF.2.1-00021-QCARMSWP-1 ip=192.168.11.148 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:132 memory:c1000000-c11fffff
```

`sudo lspci` yields:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 3e35 (rev 0c)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 3ea1 (rev 02)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 0c)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th/8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP Thermal Controller (rev 30)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP USB 3.1 xHCI Controller (rev 30)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP Shared SRAM (rev 30)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 30)
00:15.1 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 30)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP MEI Controller #1 (rev 30)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI Mode] (rev 30)
00:19.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP Serial IO I2C Host Controller (rev 30)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f0)
00:1d.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #10 (rev f0)
00:1d.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #13 (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d85 (rev 30)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller (rev 30)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP SMBus Controller (rev 30)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP SPI Controller (rev 30)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 07)
02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 31)
03:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: KIOXIA Corporation Device 0001
```

It is acting like the OS just stopped seeing the adapter altogether. Anybody know how to fix this? The hardware is only like 14 months old.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to include the output of `sudo lshw -c network` and `sudo lspci`? This will list some specific information about your hardware, making it more likely that someone can offer a specific solution 

Comment: Alright. Maybe that helps. Tx.